# Magento 2.0.12, 404 error(whoops, our bad) on all pages except Home, after fresh installation

Tags: 404-page, .htaccess

After doing a fresh installation of Magento 2.0.12.
I am getting "whoops, our bad" page for all pages except the homepage(index).
The homepage load fine but for all other pages/links , I m getting this 404 error.

I tried adding Rewritebase / in the .htaccess, but it didn't change anything.

Can please someone help.
Here's is how the values in .htaccess looks like.

---

DirectoryIndex index.php

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off


    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off


    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off


    SSLOptions StdEnvVars


    RewriteBase /
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

    RedirectMatch 403 /.git
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
    
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have enabled **mod_rewrite** apache module. After enabling it, restart apache server.

In ubuntu, you can do as per following steps.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already in effect. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I already have mod_write enabled and also AllowOverride set to All. What else could be causing it?